# what happens if we create stored procedure without synonym?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I have created a stored procedure without having synonym , because i don't know the importance of synonym. In my project we use two databases for development and another just to create synonyms.I had created stored proc with three input parameters and two output parameters in development database and also I executed my stored proc, it compiled successfully and got output. My question is can I create in this fashion? what happens if there isn't synonym created for a stored procedure. If it is a must then how did I get the output?. can we create synonym for a stored procedure which has input and output parameters. can any one help me out from this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What makes you think a stored procedure needs a synonym? You don't need a synonym with a stored procedure. Perhaps your development team uses them for security reasons. You should understand the purposes for creating synonyms in your development environment

Comment: I agree with  Nick.McDermaid. I guess your development schema is something like code owner and another one has grants for execute procedures and read (maybe write) tables and it is used for users access. It's common solution...

Comment: Ya thanks for the suggestion, made it clear

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you do not need to create synonyms for stored procedures.

However there might be cases when synonym is needed.

> A synonym is an **alternative name** for objects such as tables, views,
>   sequences, **stored procedures**, and other database objects.
>
> You generally use synonyms when you are granting access to an object
>   **from another schema** and you don't want the users to have to worry
>   about knowing which schema owns the object.

So just read on oracle synonyms and decide whether you need to use them or not.
([synonyms](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php), [create synonym](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm))